# Header may not contain more than a single header - new line detected

Tags: php, laravel

> Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

How to resolve it?

View:

```
@if (Session::has('message-reset-password'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message-reset-password') }}</div>
@endif
```

ResetPasswordController:

```
public function redirectTo(){
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('profil')->with('message-reset-password', 'Hasło zostało zmienione.');
    } else {
        return redirect('login')->with('message-reset-password', 'Hasło zostało zmienione. Można teraz się zalogować.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method redirectTo() cannot return a redirect(), it should always return URL path

```
  public function redirectTo(){
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return '/somewhere/someuri';
        } else {
            return '/somewhere/someotheruri';
        }
    }
```

More about it: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Auth/AuthenticationException.html#method_redirectTo

Comment: Ok, but how to display this message after this step? Its my the worst problem.

Comment: @Marbeat you can try  `$request->session()->flash('message', 'Hasło zostało zmienione.!');`

Comment: Ok I found something like that. It will solve the problem. I will back soon with reply ☺ thanks for help

Comment: Its working now with:
```public function redirectTo () {

if (Auth::check()) { session()->flash('message-reset-password', 'Hasło zostało zmienione.'); 
return ('profil'); } 
else { 
session()->flash('message-reset-password', 'Hasło zostało zmienione. Można teraz się zalogować.'); 
return ('login'); } }```